# Image rollover effect and text below the image

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I'm trying to make an image rollover effect with text below the image that only appears when you hover over the image. When I hover over the image the text appears, but if I hover over the text the image doesn't stay active.

How do I keep the image activated even when I hover over the text?

```css
#wrapper .text {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#wrapper:hover .text {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/723561620761391104/BQmg7aTz_400x400.jpg" 
    onmouseover="this.src='http://www.clickborde.com.br/image/data/produtos/prod_2109_815807521.jpg'" 
    onmouseout="this.src='http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/723561620761391104/BQmg7aTz_400x400.jpg'">
    
  <p class="text" style="text-align: left;">TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest binding the event listeners to the `#wrapper` element rather than the image itself. That way, both `:hover` and `onmouse` events are bound to the same element. For example:

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var image = document.getElementById('theimage');
wrapper.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  image.src = '//www.clickborde.com.br/image/data/produtos/prod_2109_815807521.jpg'
})
wrapper.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  image.src = '//pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/723561620761391104/BQmg7aTz_400x400.jpg';
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 80px;
}
#wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .2);
}

#wrapper .text {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#wrapper:hover .text {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img id="theimage" src="//pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/723561620761391104/BQmg7aTz_400x400.jpg">
  <p class="text">TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
</div>
```

---

### Edit

Here's another method using only CSS. Both images are included in the HTML and their display modes are toggled upon `#wrapper` hover.

```css
img {
  max-width: 80px;
}

#wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .2);
}

.image_off {
  display: block;
}
.image_on {
  display: none;
}

#wrapper:hover .image_off {
  display: none;
}
#wrapper:hover .image_on {
  display: block;
}

#wrapper .text {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#wrapper:hover .text {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img class="image_off" src="//pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/723561620761391104/BQmg7aTz_400x400.jpg">
  <img class="image_on" src="//www.clickborde.com.br/image/data/produtos/prod_2109_815807521.jpg">
  <p class="text">TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a rule so the hover of the text triggers its own visibility as well. (note that I changed the `src` and `onmouseout` values as the link seems to be dead, adjust this back for your final use)

```css
#wrapper .text {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#wrapper:hover .text,
#wrapper .text:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="http://www.clickborde.com.br/image/data/produtos/prod_2109_815807521.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.clickborde.com.br/image/data/produtos/prod_2109_815807521.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.clickborde.com.br/image/data/produtos/prod_2109_815807521.jpg'">

  <p class="text" style="text-align: left;">TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrapper:hover .text, .text:hover {
visibility:visible;
}
```